# Using javascript builtin functions within the function node of Node-RED

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I am new to Node-Red. I am trying to use the builtin functions from Javascript in my function node.

My function node code is:

```
msg.payload = { "time" : 
    toString(getHours()) + ":" + 
        toString(getMinutes()) }
return msg;
```

but I get the following error even though getHours() is a builtin javascript function:
"ReferenceError: getHours is not defined (line 2, col 14)"

Can you please help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `getHours()` is not a builtin.

Comment: `getHours()` is only defined for [Date.prototype.getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours#Syntax)

Comment: `getHours()` and `toString()` are not global functions.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
let date = new Date();

msg.payload = { "time" : date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() }
return msg;
```

Comment: Thanks Piotr, it works... I have to learn a bit of JavaScript as well :)